# Go check if bufio reader is empty

Tags: go

```
var r bufio.Reader
```

How do I check if `r` has no more data (is empty, is depleted)?

I understand that this may need to block until that information is known.

Can't find anything searching Google. I thought the `Peek` function would be useful to see if there is more data, but this seems to only peek an underlying buffer if exists. I could also try to `Read` one byte and subsequently call `UnreadByte` but that's extremely messy and unclear, are there any better options?

Comment: The buffered reader does not expose that; if you read and the buffer is empty, it reads more from the underlying `Reader`. When *that* reader is empty, `Read` should return `io.EOF`.

Comment: You might try r.Buffered()

Comment: @Adrian The problem with read is that it will advance.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of the buffered reader. If you don't want it to automatically read more from the backing reader, don't use it; just read directly from the underlying reader into your own `[]byte` buffer. Then you'll know how much of that you've read.

Comment: If Peek(1) returns data, then the next call to Read will return data. If there's no data in the buffer, then Peek calls to the underlying reader.   Does that do what you need?

Comment: @CeriseLimón That's exactly what I want! I must have misread something somewhere and thought Peek behaved differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `r.Peek(1)` returns data, then the next call to [Read](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.Read) will return data.

If there's no data in the buffer, then [Peek](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.Peek) calls to the underlying reader and will block until data is available or an error.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, would this work?

```golang
// func (*Reader) Size() int
// Size returns the size of the underlying buffer in bytes.
size := r.Size()

// func (*Reader) Buffered() int
// Buffered returns the number of bytes that can be read from the current buffer
buffered := r.Buffered()
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this can help me?